# Ansible check mode giving error on copy task

Tags: linux, ansible

I am running a playbook in check mode meaning I run the playbook with the `--check` flag. I need to transfer files from one node to the ansible control node and then from the control node to a remote node. I use the `fetch` module to get the file onto the control node and then the next task I want to copy the file I just got to the remote node. Syntax for the play is simple

```yaml
- name : COpy files
  become: yes
  copy:
       src: /etc/file/path
       dest: /etc/file/path
```

On this play I get an error

> Could not find or access /etc/filepath on the Ansible Controller. If you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option

Is it possible that this play is failing in check mode since the files from the previous fetch command are not actually copied to the control node? I thought that the task would just be skipped over but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that this play is failing in check mode since the files from the previous fetch command are not actually copied to the control node?

Have you investigated this option? Hint: the answer is definitely yes.

You have two options to overcome this issue.

1. You decide that fetching the files from remote to localhost is not a problem even in check mode and does not change the overall system state. In this case the previous task in your playbook should look like:

   ```yaml
   - name: Get files from remote
     fetch:
       src: /my/file/path
       dest: /etc/file/path
     check_mode: false
     changed_when: false
     delegate_to: some_other_host
   ```

   In this case the files will still be fetched and will exist to check the next task.
2. You do not want at all to get the files in check mode. In that case you want to make sure the task copying the files will not stop you playbook. You have two possible options:

   - (my prefered) completely skip the task when running in check mode

     ```yaml
     - name : Copy files
       become: yes
       copy:
         src: /etc/file/path
         dest: /etc/file/path
       when: not ansible_check_mode
     ```
   - let the task run but ignore errors when running in check mode:

     ```yaml
     - name : Copy files
       become: yes
       copy:
         src: /etc/file/path
         dest: /etc/file/path
       ignore_errors: "{{ ansible_check_mode }}"
     ```

Comment: You were correct . This was causing the issue. I used the ignore_errors option you mentioned and was able to check my playbook. Thank you.